# Flutter build linking failed ttcIndex not found after upgrading to flutter v1.12.13

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter app was working without any issue and it worked after I upgraded to flutter `v1.12.13+hotfix.5` on debug mode but I get this error when I try to build an `APK`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
>   > 1 exception was raised by workers:   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   >     linking failed
>   >     D:\my-flutter-app\build\shared_preferences\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:236:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/fontVaria tionSettings not found.
>   >     D:\my-flutter-app\build\shared_preferences\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:237:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.   error: failed
>   >     linking references.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Running
>   Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       7.9s
>   Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

My flutter doctor shows no issues

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.18362.592], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

I'm sure that my `build.gradle` contains `compileSdkVersion 28` which is the typical solution for this issue and everything was working before I upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to find this line in your error log

> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   linking failed [your project path]\build`the package that has the
>   problem` \intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml

To solve the issue

1- open android studio

2- open the android project of your app. (take care not NOT the app itself)

3- on the left make sure that you view in "project" or "android" view

4- You will find all your packages listed, open expand `the package that has the problem`\android

5- open `the package that has the problem` build.gradle

6- make sure that `compileSdkVersion 28` not 27

In my case `the package that has the problem` was `shared_preferences`
For more information check [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27226) on flutter github repo

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, the command `flutter config --enable-build-plugin-as-aar` helped me, [from here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23586#issuecomment-518886736)

Comment: Thanks for your support but I need it as APK to sent to the client, I don't want the aar now